# Rails_Admin Multiple 'User' Models + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-admin

So I have installed Devise and rails_admin in my current setup. I'm kinda trying out rails right now for administration scenarios.

Since I figured many administration required multiple 'user' models, I ran into trouble in figuring out the right way to design and arrange their relationships.

So right now I have a User (devise) model.

For the User Models, I decided to separate the models I need (Admin, Student(example), Professor(example)).

I read around and found out that STI seems to be the solution here, so I set them up to be

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     devise :database_authenticatable, 
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

class Student < User
end

class Professor < User
end
```

In rails_admin, User CRUD is basically done, and using this setup I managed to find the configuration I want. Creating a Student, for example, will be recognized as a user. However, what I'm having problems is now on whether I have the correct setup or not since I might actually need a Student to have their own attributes (like student_id or major? just throwing things here). Using the previous setup I mentioned will only enable me to create them using the User model attributes, not the Student itself.

I also read from somewhere that I need to have a column 'type' in User that can be filled with either Student or Professor, but I'm having trouble in combining all of this solutions.

Any pointers/suggestions on how I should proceed now? Much appreciated.

Comment: Got it working by using polymorphic associations. However, creating a User that is a student through rails_admin requires me to first create a 'Student' entity, and only then will creating a User allow me to set the Student entity as a user and the user as a student. This looks cumbersome and would be better if I can create a student directly instead of going back and forth to the user section. Any ideas on that? Also how would I set to see attributes from the user model in the Student section? I set attributes like name to the 'User' and left the student with 'major' etc.

Comment: Just a suggestion: if the answers below works for you, you might want to accept it? Also, you might want to post the comment above as two new questions, 1) rails_admin, 2) accessing attributes.

Comment: @roob, right sorry for the delay. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decide to use Single Table Inheritance:

- the `type` attribute is used by Rails to reach the appropriate model and its done automatically for you. i.e. when you do a `Student.new`, the `type` attribute is set to "Student"
- the attributes of all the inherited classes ( Student, Professor, etc) are all stored in the `users` table. This means that both Student and Professor will have `major`, `fees_schedule`, etc (which are not normally applicable to professors).

Here's the documentation about [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)

On the other hand, you might want to consider **Polymorphic Associations** where each table is separate and associated along the lines of:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member, polymorphic: true
  ...
end

class StudentMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :member
  ...
end

class ProfessorMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :member
  ...
end
```

Read more about Polymorphic Associations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Polymorphic Associations seems more appropriate in your case as there are probably many different attributes for students, professors, admin staff, etc, and it will look pretty messy if you dump all of them into the `users` table.

Comment: Hi, got it working by using polymorphic associations. Now I can see that Student is separate from User. However, creating a User that is a student through rails_admin requires me to first create a 'Student' entity, and only then will creating a User allow me to set the Student entity as a user and the user as a student. This looks cumbersome and would be better if I can create a student directly instead of going back and forth to the user section. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use rails_admin and can't really help you there.